# Building Postgresql C function with Multidimensional Array as input

Tags: c, postgresql

I am extending the Postgresql functions using the C SPI. The function needs to be able to take in a Postgres N-Dim Array and get the data out of it. I am able to get the data from a 1D array but I get a segfault when trying to access a N-Dim array.

My first try to just access an element was simply

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(sum_elements);
Datum
matmul(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{

    ArrayType *anyArray = PG_GETARG_ARRAYTYPE_P(0);
    int32 **a = (int32 **)  ARR_DATA_PTR(anyArray);



    PG_RETURN_INT64(a[1][1]);
}
```

I also tried as if it flattened the matrix into a 1D array but the values that came out were just garbage.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the deconstruct_array (..) function to extract the values. This function will give you a Datum type pointer.

Example of the book:

```
deconstruct_array(input_array, //one-dimensional array
                  INT4OID, //of integers
                  4,//size of integer in bytes
                  true,//int4 is pass-by value
                  'i',//alignment type is 'i'
                  &datums, &nulls, &count); // result here
```

"The datums pointer will be set to point to an array filled with actual elements."

You can access the values using:

```
DatumGetInt32(datums[i]);
```